# How to view PS Scheduled Jobs As Another User

Tags: scheduled-tasks, credentials, powershell-3.0, windows-server-2012, job-scheduling

I recently created over 30 PS Scheduled Jobs. The jobs run under the credentials of a service account. After importing PSScheduledJob, Get-Job will get the jobs and I can retrieve the job output. No problem so far.

I created another Windows Task (not PS scheduled) to report on any failed PS Scheduled jobs. The reporting task executes under the same service account as the PS jobs. However, the reporting job can not find ANY PS jobs!

I assume because the PS jobs were registered under user "A", user "B" can't find the "Output" because the jobs are associated with User "A" and output is stored under that user. Even though the PS jobs run under user "B", the output is still stored with the user who *created* the job.

Is there a way for user "B" to retrieve the job Output of user "A"? if not, is there an easy way to reregister the Jobs under User "B"?